# Putting version information in manifest file into JAR using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to find a way of putting version information in manifest file into JAR using Maven?

For WAR files I use the following in my POM.XML

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and then I run "**mv clean package**"

How would you do this for a JAR.. Can you please give me details information on the changes and the commands... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven-jar-plugin (the configuration is nearly the same as maven-war-plugin)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <index>true</index>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <mode>development</mode>
          <url>${project.url}</url>
          <key>value</key>
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

Here the documentation of the plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html

And all options: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html